# jquery $.ajax request remains pending in IE 11 alone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Am using polling method in my project. For that, process makes an asynchronous ajax call to server until get the result. I could able to process the request and got response from in all browsers(all versions) except IE 11.0.9600.1760. In IE 11, it remains pending state even i cant able to debug this request.

Please some one advise me to resolve this issue. If you faced problem like this already?

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Could you include any code, please?

Comment: Our psychic abilities are not what they will be... Please provide your code so we have some slim hope of helping you :)

Comment: I think, code isn't matter. Cause same code works very well in staging environment. It is happening in production alone.

Comment: @RameshRR faced the same, do you find unything on this issue?